# Optimising Images for Banners

Tags: css, html, optimization, banner, retina

Bit of a time sensitive question here, so any timely responses would be very, very appreciated.

I have to create some HTML5 banners of varying sizes, some for mobile, others for desktop. My limit for each is 100kb. I have been given images and text in InDesign files.

What is the best way to optimise these images and text-groups?

So far I have been turning them into PNG-8s using Fireworks, with average results. If they're average now, they're going to look terrible on Retina screens. I don't want that.

To counter that, should I save them in larger sizes and scale them in the HTML5/CSS?

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but I've searched around all afternoon and can't find a workable answer. Please help if you can.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Fair enough.

. Is there a way to bring into sprite sheet into HTML5 and shrink it down in order to use it for that banner. I've been trying to make it work as a background-image but am stuck because to scale it down (background-size 50% 50%) for example, requires that it be a set-size, which is not particularly ideal for a sprite sheet.  Using CSS Transform:scale reduces the entire element, which, again, throws everything out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from deploying the HTML5 `<picture>` element:

**Further Reading:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture
2. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015